# Why Can't Kotlin Infer The Type For Comparator

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

Reading the Java interop document about [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions), I expected the Kotlin function

`Collections.sortWith(comparator: kotlin.Comparator<in T> /* = java.util.Comparator<in T> */)`

to be able to take a lambda function without needing to explicitly specify the parameter is a Comparator. However the following code gives `type inference failed`:

```
val someNumbers = arrayListOf(1, 5, 2)
someNumbers.sortWith({ x, y -> 1 })
```

whereas:

```
val someNumbers = arrayListOf(1, 5, 2)
someNumbers.sortWith(Comparator { x, y -> 1 })
```

compiles and runs correctly

Comment: Interestingly it works for `Collections.sort(arrayList, { x, y -> 1 })`

Comment: if `sortWith` would rather accept a comparator of type `comparator: (T, T) -> Int` it would work without specifying `Comparator`... but I don't know what I should do with that information for now ;-) And that would actually not help that much, as we would then would need `Collections.sort.(this) { x, y -> comparator(x, y) }` within `sortedWith` instead.... (I'm just thinking out loud)

Comment: Very interesting read: [Kotlin issue #7770 - SAM for Kotlin classes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770) and maybe also worth a thumbs up ;-) Also: [#11129 SAM conversion for kotlin function](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11129)... maybe there is something coming in 1.3... didn't see it yet though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the comments from the [Kotlin issue 'SAM for Kotlin classes'](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770) I learned a lot regarding the SAM conversion and why `typealias` was introduced, but not yet why this specific behaviour wasn't solved yet... and I am not the only one as the issue and its comments show.

Summarizing, the SAM conversion was only considered for Java interfaces (compare also [this comment](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-and-sam-interface-with-two-parameters/293/2)). Jetbrains did work on (or still needs to do) a bigger refactoring and tries to solve that issue so that SAMs are also available for Kotlin functions themselves (compare also [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770#focus=streamItem-27-2919336-0-0)). They are trying to support [SAM conversion for kotlin functions in a separate issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11129), which could come with 1.3. As I am currently testing 1.3: I did not see anything regarding this yet. So maybe, if you like the SAM conversion as I do, you may want to upvote either [SAM for Kotlin classes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770) or [SAM conversion for kotlin function](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11129) or both.

By the way: [a very similar example was also used by Ilya Gorbunov using `arrayOf().sort`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770#focus=streamItem-27-1210104-0-0).

Comment: Nice find. My favourite part is "I had to create java interfaces in my kotlin project just because the lack of this feature." https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770#focus=streamItem-27-2214344-0-0 So there is a workaround, at least for your own code.

Comment: well... to be honest, I would rather want to live without workarounds ;-) I can't really understand why `sortWith` uses a `Comparator`-parameter, if we have the "nice functional types"... in this specific case I will probably rather use `sort(someNumbers) { x, y -> 1 }` with a `Collections.sort`-import... it's shorter, nicely readable and it allows me to use SAM conversion.